# Java Graphics - paramaters in paint method

Tags: java, graphics, paint

I have a function which returns 4 values in an array, which are coordinates of two points e.g x1,y1,x2,y2 .

```
public int[] Get_Coord(){
    int[] result = new int[4];
    //Do something
    ...

    return results;

}
```

I want to draw a line according to these values. Something like that:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){

    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

But, paint doesnt get any parameters except Graphics g. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Call your function inside paint method and you are done.

Comment: `I have a function which returns 4 values in an array` - in Java that is called a "method" and method names should not start with an upper case character. Please use proper terminology and follow Java naming conventions when you ask a question so everybody understands what you are asking.

Comment: Also you should not be overriding the paint() method. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.